# 1x09 Emanations - How to recover the shroud?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Yesterday I watched **1x09 Emanations** and wondered.

In that episode, they discover a species who send their dead – or *soon-dead* – into a machine. In this a quantum anomaly reigns which teleports them into another dimension and/or onto an asteroid.

[image: Hello]

*Hello, I'm that machine he talks about.*

Harry Kim has been teleported to that species and was set off to be widely examined. As he wanted to go back to Voyager and another entity of that species has been send there to be soon-dead, he had a plan:

"Wrap me in your shroud, *which has been used about five generations* in your family, you run away and I pretend to be dead. That's how I'm going back for free." (Not exactly the original soundtrack.)

[image: Hello again]

*Shrouded Harry Kim pretending to be the families'* soon-dead

They did it. Kim wrapped himself into that family shroud, went into the machine, was ported to the asteroid and then beamed up to the Voyager.

**How did the family recover that ancient shroud from their fathers and their father's father when it gets ported completely (to be seen with Harry Kim) into another dimension/unreachable space?**

Have I been missing something or was this just a narrative mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The "[subspace vacuole](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/108.htm)" device used by the Vhnori **only transfers the body, not clothing**.

As you can see from the pics below when they find Ptera she appears to be naked, albeit covered with some kind of gauzy webbing. The (blue and white) shroud that she left behind can clearly be seen inside the chamber when they remove Harry Kim.

[image: Ptera Emanations]
[image: Harry Kim Shroud]

Similarly, when they transfer Harry he is wearing a shroud but the next time we see him (in Sick Bay) he is naked and covered with a sheet despite having been "transported directly".

If the shroud remains in the chamber then there is no issue with it being reused generationally.

Comment: Wow, that's what i missed, thanks! At first I thougt Harry was naked in the medical bay because they wanted to scan the shizzle out of him - safety for a ressurection. But your answer fits to the whole episode. Man, I need glasses...

Comment: Well on average Voyager does make lots of mistakes narratively as well as chronologically (like when they traveled back to the 1990's and there's no Eugenics War) so if you're watching the series all the way through prepare for a large amount of forehead slapping.

Comment: but we all still love it anyway, mainly because of Jeri Ryan's outfit.

Comment: She's not bad. If I had to give her a score it would be seven of nine...